# Does HTML(5) ignore graphemes?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, html-parsing

A [grapheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) is the smallest "unit" in writing. In English, we normally just think of the characters A-Z, but other languages have accents. UTF allows you to add accents to characters to form a grapheme. There's a [generalized algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) that lets you break a sequence of UTF code points into logical grapheme clusters (where each cluster of code points represents a single grapheme).

Take, for example, the following:

> <̖̈̌̍br>̗̘̈̉̊̋

There are four graphemes in the above text: `<̖̈̌̍`, `b`, `r`, and `>̗̘̈̉̊̋` (note that `<̖̈̌̍` and `>̗̘̈̉̊̋` are really just `<` and `>` with additional accents). If I put this in the HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <̖̈̌̍br>̗̘̈̉̊̋
  </body>
</html>
```

it fails to validate using the experimental validators I've found. These validators seem to parse using code points, not graphemes, and thus complain about the accent code points that follow `<` (which fails to form a valid HTML5 tag).

Given that these validators are experimental, I don't know if I should fully trust their results.

Does HTML5 ignore graphemes, and only care about code points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**2.1.6 Character encodings**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#encoding-terminology) of the HTML spec says:

> The term **Unicode code point** means a *Unicode scalar value* where possible, and an isolated surrogate code point when not. When a conformance requirement is defined in terms of characters or Unicode code points, a pair of [code units](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#code-unit) consisting of a high surrogate followed by a low surrogate must be treated as the single code point represented by the surrogate pair, but isolated surrogates must each be treated as the single code point with the value of the surrogate.
>
> In this specification, the term **character**, when not qualified as *Unicode* character, is synonymous with the term [Unicode code point](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#unicode-code-point).
>
> The term **Unicode character** is used to mean a *Unicode scalar value* (i.e. any Unicode code point that is not a surrogate code point).

Then, later, in [*8.1.2.1 Start tags*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) and  [*8.1.2.2 End tags*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags) it defines things using the word *character* (which, from above, we know is synonymous with *Unicode code point*).

This means that when it encounters `<̖̈̌̍`, it's really just parsing the sequence of code points [U+003C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003c/index.htm), [U+0316](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0316/index.htm), [U+0308](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm), [U+030C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030c/index.htm), and [U+030D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030d/index.htm). It ignores the notion of grapheme.

Interestingly, this means that the closing tag, `>̗̘̈̉̊̋` is still a "valid" HTML closing tag. The sequence of code points is [U+003E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003e/index.htm), [U+0317](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0317/index.htm), [U+0318](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0318/index.htm), [U+0308](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm), [U+0309](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0309/index.htm), [U+030A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030a/index.htm), and [U+030B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030b/index.htm). The first code point (U+003E) is just `>`, so it's consumed as a closing tag. The following code points, which are [combining code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), are then just normal "text" as far as the parser is concerned (which isn't quite valid UTF). It remains a question, then, what the renderer will do: do the combining code points just get rendered as garbage, or will they be combined with the character preceding the tag that was just closed?

The conclusion, though, is that graphemes aren't used in HTML parsing. Just code points.

Comment: +1 ...and this is how it should be, since the rules for calculating grapheme boundaries are wildly complex and subject to continual revision. They shouldn't be part of a markup parser. Code points *should* indeed be the unit of parsing, although the DOM string model thereafter is based on UTF-16 code units rather than code points, and in some cases it's possible to sneak invalid surrogate sequences through the parser.